# Web-page controls on Mac OS X

Tags: html, css, macos

It looks like controls like `<input>` `<select>` and `<button>` cant' be affected by CSS properties such as font-size (and some others). However, the font-size is actually could be different I saw, but how to control it?

For instance I want to have the font-size and font-family to be the same for normal text and for controls. How to do that?

If you have a solution, try to base it on this example: http://jsfiddle.net/uff8q/2/

**UPD I'm talking about Mac OS X (I tried Chrome and Safari)**

Comment: Firefox / Windows 7: http://i.imgur.com/mBx4B.png / http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/uff8q/3/ - I don't think I can help you :) It already looks the same for me.

Comment: your example works just fine. What browser are you using ? you can change the font size **exactly** like you're doing it

Comment: Just so you know, my previous example also works in Chrome/Safari in Windows, so it looks like it's a Mac OS X only thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on the browser.

- `<input>` items can be full styled in any browser. You can change the font, size and colours.
- `<select>` items can be fully styled in Firefox, but not Safari/Chrome. You cannot change the font very much — there are only three sizes.

Update: here are the three sizes you can get with WebKit:

```
<select style="font-size: 10px;">
<option>Foobar</option>
</select>

<select style="font-size: 11px;">
<option>Foobar</option>
</select>

<select style="font-size: 16px;">
<option>Foobar</option>
</select>
```

And a picture:

[image]

Comment: how to control these three sizes?